# JS - Safari on iOS - How to get viewport scale property

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, window, viewport

On Chrome, I can get the viewport scale by looking at `window.visualViewport.scale` it is available on Safari, however, it seems that `window.visualViewport` is not defined on older versions of **Safari on iOS**.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you need to get viewport width by using **clientWidth** or **innerWidth**

```
var viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
```

Then, you need to get actual screen width

```
var screenWidth = window.screen.width
```

Then, viewport scale is on your hand

```
var viewportScale = screenWidth / viewportWidth
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=visualViewport%20scale) `visualViewport.scale` should be available in Safari for iOS from version 13.0 which was released 19 September 2019. Have you updated yet?

If you really need to support older Safari for iOS, and also if you have no need to measure scale right at the page load, you can try to catch [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) and guess/calculate scale by yourself.

If you're going to really desperate, you can try to "invent some bicycle". For example (just the concept): create and measure 2 `<div>` right inside `<body>`. One of them `width: 100vw;` and another `width: 100%;` (this actually isn't needed since blocks already will be 100% width of parent block). The trick here would be in different units. **100vw** should be always 100% of the viewport, when **100%** should stretch for maximum available width. Measure the difference between those 2 blocks and you can calculate scale. Be aware of those tricky margins/paddings and maybe of the landscape.

Comment: If you use position fixed you should be able to avoid potential layout issues. And some combination of portrait/landscape media queries should help with people rotating their phones and throwing the scale calculation off. Ex: portrait 100%/vw, landscape 100%/vh